# Use drop-down to a column in data-frame in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python coding. I have created one summarized data-frame in python with details of few models and wants to make that data more interactive with the addition of drop-down to one of column

I tried using dash in plotly but unable to understand and not able to get it.

Data-frame looks like this

```
  Accuracy  Precision   threshold   Recall  Model

0   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    PCA

1   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    PCA

4   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    Random Forrest

5   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    Random Forrest

7   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    KNN

8   0.9     0.9            0.9       0.9    KNN
```

I want to apply drop-down in model column based upon their unique names and wants to add line chart for same using same drop down

Comment: check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/bring-your-jupyter-notebook-to-life-with-interactive-widgets-bc12e03f0916). Are you looking to do something like this?

Comment: Thanks bro. Yes it was the same i was looking for